# TSQL - Compare two dates [TRIGGER and IF]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to compare two dates, @DataJogo with @DataEvento and want to check if the play date is later than the date of the event.

The Trigger works only when the insert is valid appears both selects the IF.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriValidaData
ON jogo
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @DataJogo date, @DataEvento date , @IDJogo int, @IDEvento int
SELECT @IDJogo = id_jogo FROM inserted
SELECT @IDEvento = id_evento FROM inserted
SELECT @DataJogo =  data FROM inserted
SELECT @DataEvento = data FROM evento WHERE id_evento = @IDEvento
IF @DataJogo > @DataEvento
    SELECT 'O jogo foi adicionado com sucesso.' AS 'MENSAGEM';
ELSE
    DELETE FROM jogo WHERE id_jogo = @IDJogo;
    SELECT 'A data não é valida. A inserção de dados não foi efectuada com sucesso.' AS 'MENSAGEM';



INSERT INTO jogo VALUES (11,'15:00:00','16:00:00','2018-05-01',3,10,0)
DELETE FROM jogo WHERE id_jogo = 11;
```

[IMAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrntN.jpg)
[IMAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRMSv.jpg)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to put the ELSE part in BEGIN... END block like this,

```
IF @DataJogo > @DataEvento BEGIN
    SELECT 'O jogo foi adicionado com sucesso.' AS 'MENSAGEM';
END
ELSE BEGIN
    DELETE FROM jogo WHERE id_jogo = @IDJogo;
    SELECT 'A data não é valida. A inserção de dados não foi efectuada com     sucesso.' AS 'MENSAGEM';
END
```

Comment: also as @Gordon pointed you can not manipulate the same table in trigger that invokes the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this with a trigger.  Do this with a check constraint:

```
alter table TriValidaData add constraint chk_TriValidaData_datas
    check (@DataJogo > @DataEvento);
```

If you want to do this using triggers, then you should use an "instead of" trigger and only update/insert into the table when the condition is true.